# Switch between accounts in GitHub

Tags: account-management, github

I have a personal and professional Gmail account. Switching between then is easy - clicking on my name in the upper-right corner opens a switching menu:

[image: switching menu]

I have two GitHub accounts as well, each associated with one of the aforementioned Gmail accounts, and switching is a real pain - I have to log out and log in again as the other user:

[image: the other user]

Any idea how to easily switch between multiple GitHub accounts on the web?

My current solution is working with two browsers, which is really awkward.

Comment: As a side note, the [GitHub Terms of Service](https://github.com/site/terms) state that "One person or legal entity may not maintain more than one free account." Your question is still valid though, as it is perfectly fine to have separate accounts provided that only one is free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. Gmail allows multiple accounts running at the same time whereas there is no such mechanism on GitHub.

Comment: Is there any way to circumnavigate this? Perhaps an add-on that handles cookies for multiple accounts?

Comment: I've heard of SessionBox for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

Comment: @thisgeek SessionBox works for me and is for some reason the last answer (and had a negative score somehow) - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138581/251479

Comment: @lustig probably as it's not a first party solution and it's against the TOS to have multiple accounts (provided both of them aren't free, as mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 1):

There are various browser add-ons that let you switch between sets of cookies. Personally, I use [Multifox for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/multifox/). Install the add-on, and it creates a Default Profile. Sign in to Github with one account, and then create a new profile, and sign in with your other account. You can now switch back and forth by switching which Profile is active.

Comment: The right answer for me was merging the accounts, but thanks!

Comment: That would obviously solve it, but unfortunately not an option in my case :) 

Any reason you chose the other post as best answer? I believe mine actually solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.Free simple and actually works.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig

Comment: I don't know why this had a negative vote score. I just came to this question, looked at the accepted and second answer that weren't simple enough, and then separately found SessionBox. Highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me so far (for all of five minutes), and is a variation on the "use a different browser to manage a different identity" advice:

- Use Chrome
- Create a "new person".  Settings -> manage other people -> add person.
- With that person, login to GitHub as whoever you'd like.
- Repeat for as many GH identities as you need, I guess.  I only have two, so YMMV there.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, finally I found a firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieprofileswitcher/?src=search

Cookie Profile Switcher allows you to easily manage multiple cookie sessions for all of your websites!